# Typescript Observable inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing some base classes to do common things and then call overridden methods in the child classes.

In the code bellow, I need to call `this.doSomethingElse` only after the user is update by user service.

this is in the base class:

```
public onSubmit() {
    this.beforeSubmit();
    this.submitForm().subscribe(() => {
      this.afterSubmit();
    });
  }
```

this is in the child class:

```
  public submitForm(): Observable<User> {
    this.userServices.update(formValues).subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.someChildAction();
      return ??? ?
    });
    return ????
  }
```

I'm not sure what to code in the `????` lines.

Comment: Have a look at my answer and try to avoid nested subscriptions.

Comment: @profanis, I can't use the first answer because I need to do some actions after the service update. The second answer calls `doSomethingElse` that child class does not know. I made some update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Return the observable from `submitForm` method without subscribing. You can then concat the observable using the `concatMap` operator.

```
public onSubmit() {
    this.doSomething();
    this.submitForm().concatMap(this.doSomethingElse.bind(this)).subscribe(() => {

    });
  }
```

```
 public submitForm(): Observable<User> {
    return this.userServices.update(formValues);
  }
```

**OR**

```
public onSubmit() {
    this.doSomething();
    this.submitForm().subscribe(() => {

    });
  }


  public submitForm(): Observable<User> {
    this.userServices.update(formValues).pipe(
      concatMap(this.doSomethingElse.bind(this)) // <-- the input of the doSomethingElse will be the response of the *update* method
     ).subscribe((user: User) => {
      // here you will have the response of the doSomethingElse
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this creating in the child class the afterSubmit() method, like this:

```
afterSubmit(user) {
  //do child stuff here
  super.afterSubmit(user);
}

submitForm(): Observable<Object> {
  return this.userServices.update(formValues);
}
```

in base class:

```
public onSubmit() {
  this.beforeSubmit();
  this.submitForm().subscribe(data => {
    this.afterSubmit(data);
  });
}

public afterSubmit(data) {
  //my common stuff here
}
```